# Android Menu (ActionBar?) change fragment on click

Tags: android

I am trying to do a simple task of setting up fragments for my activity to change between them when a menu item is selected.

1. Is this a proper android design pattern? In iOS I would have separate view controllers for each "Tab", but it seems in Android you are suppose to have 1 activity with many fragments.
2. Is there example code for creating a simple menu with fragments as thats what I am trying to do.

(I am finding that android documentation is not up to par with iOS)

main_menu.xml

```
<item
    android:id="@+id/need_to_know_menu_item"
    android:showAsAction="ifRoom|withText"
    android:title="@string/need_to_know"
    />
<item
    android:id="@+id/schedule_menu_item"
    android:showAsAction="ifRoom|withText"
    android:title="@string/schedule"
    />
    <item
    android:id="@+id/news_menu_item"
    android:showAsAction="ifRoom|withText"
    android:title="@string/news"
    />
    <item
    android:id="@+id/map_menu_item"
    android:showAsAction="ifRoom|withText"
    android:title="@string/map"
    />
        <item
    android:id="@+id/tweets_menu_item"
    android:showAsAction="ifRoom|withText"
    android:title="@string/tweets"
    />
        <item
    android:id="@+id/players_menu_item"
    android:showAsAction="ifRoom|withText"
    android:title="@string/players"
    />
```

MainActivity.java

```
package com.example.app;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.ActionBar;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main_menu, menu);
        getActionBar().setHomeButtonEnabled(true);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item)
    {
        switch(item.getItemId())
        {
            case android.R.id.home:
            case R.id.need_to_know_menu_item:
                Intent intent = new Intent(this, MainActivity.class);
                intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
                startActivity(intent);
                return true;

            case R.id.schedule_menu_item:
                return true;

            case R.id.news_menu_item:
                return true;

            case R.id.map_menu_item:
                return true;

            case R.id.tweets_menu_item:
                return true;

            case R.id.players_menu_item:
                return true;

            default:
                return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);

        }
    }

}
```

Comment: What you're trying to do, is when the user clicks on specific menu item, it shows him the appropriate activity... so.. this is the way to do it.. but i think you need the menu in each activity to have the ability to navigate to any activity from each one.. and one more thing.. when you navigate to some activity A to activity B, you need to finish activity A.. except the main activity

Comment: I wasn't sure if starting a new activity was the right thing to do. Is it? I guess I can include the menu in each activity.

Comment: one more thing - you need to declare each activity in the manifest.xml file..

Comment: so your question is how to create a general menu bar that will showed up in each activity?

Comment: i don't think there is a way to do it.. 
because in each activity you declare something else.. when you're in Activity A the menu will show you item2,item3,item4.. and when you're in Activity B the menu will show you item1,item3,item4.. you have to duplicate the 'onOptionSelectedItem()' in each activity but in each activity there will be some changes in this method

Comment: Chris, i found some tutorial that can be useful 
try this one http://www.kpbird.com/2011/05/androidbottom-tabbar-control.html

Answer (score 0):

> Is this a proper android design pattern?

It's a little odd, in that it results in a rather heavyweight activity for no obvious reason.

Fragments are usually for places where you are looking to have different mixes of content based upon screen size (e.g., list-and-details on the screen at the same time on a tablet, but visible one at a time on a phone). Fragments are also sometimes used in specialty UIs for bulk-replacing content, such as tabs or a `ViewPager`.

A more conventional approach, for places where you want to change the full screen contents, is to have separate activities.

> In iOS I would have separate view controllers for each "Tab"

iOS's definition of "tab" presumably differs from Android's definition of "tab", as you are not implementing tabs here.

> but it seems in Android you are suppose to have 1 activity with many fragments

If you were implementing tabs, that would be an appropriate approach. You are not implementing tabs.

> Is there example code for creating a simple menu with fragments as thats what I am trying to do.

Probably not, as it is not something that you ordinarily would do. That being said, you are welcome to `commit()` a `replace()` `FragmentTransction` in the various `case` blocks of your `onOptionsItemSelected()`, if you wanted. Something like:

```
getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
                             .replace(android.R.id.content,
                                  new OtherFragment()).commit();
```

This presumes that the original UI of this activity is also created using a fragment and a `FragmentTransaction`, which your code does not show.

> I am finding that android documentation is not up to par with iOS

You are certainly welcome to your opinion, irrelevant and detrimental as expressing it is to your getting help here.

Comment: yes.. but as i see from his code he is starting a new activity so what is wrong with his code?

Comment: If I make every menu item a new activity, it would seem I would have to duplicate the menu in each activity. What I am trying to figure out is how to translate a tab bar controller in iOS to Android.

Comment: @Elior: I am not aware that there is anything wrong with his code.

Comment: @ChrisMuench: "it would seem I would have to duplicate the menu in each activity" -- first, the menu won't be completely the same, as you would be removing the item for the particular thing you are on . Beyond that, it is the same menu resource (adjusted in Java for the item removal), so the only duplication is some code in `onOptionsItemSelected()`, which you could delegate to a single static implementation if you so chose. Do not make a strategic choice about architecture based upon the potential duplication of a dozen or so lines of code.

Comment: @ChrisMuench: "What I am trying to figure out is how to translate a tab bar controller in iOS to Android" -- that could be a menu. It could be action bar tabs. It could be a `ViewPager` with a tab-style indicator.